# Global variables in classes laravel 4

Tags: variables, laravel, global

I have something like this

```
class Unilevel {

    public $contador = 2;

    public static function listarLevels($user_id){
        if($contador <= 5){
            echo '<h1>Nivel '.$contador.'</h1>';

            $user = DB::table('matrices')->where('id_user', $user_id)->first();

            $actual_user =  DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id_user)->first();
            echo  $actual_user->username.'<br>'; 
        }

        $contador++;
    }
}
```

The function is not working but if i put the variable $contador inside listarLevels works
which is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is how classes work in PHP.

To call `$contador` within the function when you've declared it as a class property, you use `$this->contador`

It may be helpful to read the manual on object oriented programming in PHP to get more familiar with it before diving into Laravel.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Yes but i know, but for example this is not working:

<?php

class Unilevel {

 public $contador = 1;

    public static function listarLevels($user_id){

     echo $this->contador;
     $this->contador = 2;

        $user = DB::table('matrices')->where('id_user', $user_id)->first();
        $actual_user =  DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id_user)->first(); 
        echo  $actual_user->username.'<br>';
        
        if($user){
         
      if($user->left_direct){
       listarLevels($user->left_direct);
      }
     }else{
      echo 'Ninguno';
     }
 }

    
}

?>

Comment: That's because it's a static function.  Static functions don't have access to `$this`.

Comment: If you make it `public static $contador = 1;`, then in your static function, you can `echo static::$contador;` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your class non static properties in static methods.

Try this.

```
class Unilevel {

    public static $contador = 2;

    public static function listarLevels($user_id){
             //self::$contador = 4;
    }
}
```

If your method is static you need make your property static too. Their are few other ways too like  instantiating the object of the class. Read more about [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) in PHP.